# Code signing error upon archive

Tags: ios, iphone-5, code-signing-certificate

`CodeSign error: Certificate identity 'iPhone Distribution: vishnu sivabalan'` appears more than once in the keychain.

The codesign tool requires there only be one.i have this error when i want to archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the Keychain Access app. There choose 'login' in the left top pane and 'certificates' in the left bottom pane. You likely have more than one distribution certificate installed in your machine. If so, please remove one of the certificates.

Answer (score 1):

once remove all copy of **vishnu sivabalan** certificate from your keychain, then again install it in keychain. it'll solve your problem.

hope this helps. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

- First of all Quit Xcode.
- If the Keychain access is open, keep it open.
- Launch Xcode now.
- See that the certificate Xcode was complaining about will be re-added
  into the keychain at launch from its cache.
- Go ahead and delete it.
- Run it..